# SpaCy: Regex pattern does not work in rule-based matcher

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to define a regular expression to use as text pattern in the entity ruler component in my spaCy model.
The aim is to add tokens with "COMP" label whenever it finds words structured like this:

- XXX-Ynnn
- XXX Ynnn
  Where 'XXX' are trigrams from a list, 'Y' is a letter and 'nnn' a digit combination.

To do so, I use the following method

```
def add_component_patterns_re(input_references, model_ruler):
    ruler = model_ruler
    ref_patterns = []
    letters = ['V', 'B', 'F', 'K', 'S']

    print("Adding component patterns")
    for ref in input_references.iloc[:, 0]:
        # print(f"Adding references for system: {ref}")
        for letter in letters:
            pattern_text = fr'{ref}(-| ){letter}[0-9]{{3}}'
            pattern = {"TEXT": {"REGEX": fr'{ref}(-| ){letter}[0-9]{{3}}'}}
            ref_patterns.append({"label":"COMP", "pattern":pattern})
    ruler.add_patterns(ref_patterns)

    return ref_patterns
```

Printing out the added patterns, it seems to me that the output list is correct. So my guess is that I am doing something wrong when defining the pattern to add to the ruler.
For information, i've also tried to change the pattern variable as a list entry, like this:

`pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": fr'{ref}(-| ){letter}[0-9]{{3}}'}}]`

But the result is the same, it can't seem to get any match.

Does someone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got

```
print(f"Adding references for system: {ref}")
    for letter in letters:
        for nnn in range(1000):
            pattern = f"{ref}-{letter}{nnn:03d}"
            ref_patterns.append({"label": "COMP", "pattern": pattern})
            pattern = f"{ref} {letter}{nnn:03d}"
            ref_patterns.append({"label": "COMP", "pattern": pattern})
```

For each pattern. The code is lengthier and a tad slower but it does the job just fine!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK in the context of NLP trigrams are meant as a series of N words (3 in this case).

I think `{ref}` is not needed in this case, take in assume that the value in you cell is `love like me-V123` taking `{ref}` you'll end up with the entire string which is not what you want, since you're only interested with `"love like me"`

So I would build the following regex, which match your case:

- `\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+-[YVBFKS]\d{3}` -> Regex with "-"
- `\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+[YVBFKS]\d{3}` -> Regex without "-"

Applying this all together in python I would end up with:

```
import re

pattern = r"\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+-[YVBFKS]\d{3}"
labeled_tokens = []

for ref in input_references.iloc[:, 0]:
    # Check if the token matches the pattern
    if re.match(pattern, ref ):
        labeled_tokens.append((ref, "COMP"))
    else:
        labeled_tokens.append((ref, None))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a couple of doubts though: if i were to use `\w+\s+\w+\s+\w`, it would get all trigrams right? Whereas I am using {ref} because it will pick from a fixed list of trigrams that i've defined. Also, I do not see how to later add the new pattern to the entity ruler in the solution you proposed. I guess I could use labeled_tokens but I think that the entity ruler does not take that structure as input for add_patterns.

Comment: As far as I understood you're iterating through a pandas column, `.iloc[:,0]` refers to all rows of the first column, so every `{ref}` will have the entire expression `love like me-V123` while you're interested only into `love like me`, so for me it's wrong to call for `{ref}`. Maybe I'm wrong, you can provide the output of the for loop with the print of `{ref}` so we can clearly see how it's made.

The addition of `COMP` takes place in `if re.match(pattern, ref ):`. If `{ref}` matches than the addition is made.